# Finding the value $h, $ given $f(x,y) = \frac{sin (x-y)}{x-y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was studying for some quizzes when I stumbled upon this question:

The function
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin (x-y)}{x-y} &x\neq y\\
h & x=y \\
 \end{cases} $$

is continuous.
What is the value of $h$?

My work:

I noticed that the answer found in my book is $h = 1,$ so I think I can get $h = 1$ by doing this:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin (x-y)}{x-y} = 1$$

because everybody knows that

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Is my train of logic correct?

Comment: Not quite - you are interested not only in what happens when $x$ and $y$ approach $0$, but also what happens when they approach *each other*, i.e. what happens near the line $y = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick mentioned, the question is asking to find $h$ when $x=y$ rather than $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$. For example, this could be the case that $x=4$ and $y=4$.$$———————$$
This question becomes significantly simpler in polar coordinates: $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$.

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{(x-y)}\quad$ becomes

$f(r,\theta)=\dfrac{\sin[r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)]}{r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}$.

Now, $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{\theta\to\frac{\pi}{4}}f(r,\theta)$.
Using L'hopital's rule, you get

$\dfrac{-r\sin\theta-r\cos\theta}{-r\sin\theta-r\cos\theta}=1\;$ at $\;\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{4} \space\space\forall{r}$.

Comment: I like to be enlightened. What is the logic behind your answer? What  is in $f(x,y) = \frac{sin (x-y)}{x-y}$ that we apply your solution that way?

Comment: When dealing with vector spaces with dim > 3, I usually transform coordinates to simplify questions. In my experience, it is often the case that when global coordinates (x,y) make a problem difficult, curvilinear coordinates (r,theta) simplify the problem and vice versa for questions of these types.

Answer (score 0):

We could also say let $a=x-y$, then notice that as $x\to y$ then $a\to 0$. So find (as you have mentioned):
$$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{\sin(a)}{a}.$$

---

Alternatively, we can write
$$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}=\frac{0}{0}$$
In this case, L'Hospital's rule can be applied to find
$$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y}=\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(x-y)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)}=\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\cos(x-y)}{1}=\cos(0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong :

$f(x,y) = f(x-y) = \frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y)}$, $x \ne y$.

Set $z: = x-y$.

$f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$, $ z \ne 0$.

$f$ is continuous at $z = 0$:

$\star)$ $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} f(z) = f(0)$.

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(z)}{z} = 1$.

$\star$):  continuity at $z=0$ implies:

$f(0) := 1$.

Comment: Seems legit XD   nice:-D