# proof that $\sin(x-y)/(x-y)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The question was implicitely already discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388668/finding-the-value-h-given-fx-y-fracsin-x-yx-y) Post.

However, the only answer which used an argument similar to my proofs isn't very detailed and I was wondering whether or not my proofs actually hold.

> We want to show that the function $$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} &x \neq y \\
> 1 &x=y \end{cases} $$
> Is continuous.

My proofs: We write $f = (g \circ \Delta) (x,y)$, where

$$(x,y) \overset{\Delta(x,y)}\mapsto x-y \qquad t \overset{g}{\mapsto} \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} & t \neq 0 \\ 1 &t=0 \end{cases} $$

**First Proof:**
The function $\Delta(x,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so is $g$, with $g(0) = 1$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous as the composition of two continuous functions on valid domains ($\Delta(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}$) and for $x=y$ we get $f(x,x) = g(\Delta(x,x)) = g(0) = 1$.

**Second Proof:** Let $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,y), (x_n,y_n) \neq (x,y)$. We have: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Delta(x_n,y_n) = \lim_{n} x_n - y_n = \lim_n x_n - \lim_n y_n = x-y = \Delta(x,y)$$ and so $\Delta$ is continuous.

For any sequence $t_n \rightarrow t \in \mathbb{R}, t_n \neq t$ we have directly for $t\neq0$ that $$\lim_n g(t_n) = \lim_n\frac{\sin(t_n)}{t_n} = \frac{\sin(t)}{t} = g(t)$$

In the case where $\lim_n t_n = 0$, we find (for ex de l'hopital or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)) that $$\lim_n g(t_n) = 1 = g(0) = g(\lim_n t_n)$$ hence $g$ is continuous.

Now, $t_n := \Delta(x_n,y_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ is a real sequence with $\lim_n t_n = x-y := t \in \mathbb{R}$ and so we get:
$$\lim_n f(x_n,y_n) = \lim_n g(x_n - y_n) = \lim_n g(t_n) = g(\lim_n t_n) = g(\lim_n \Delta(x_n,y_n)) = g(\Delta(\lim_n(x_n,y_n)) = g(\Delta(x,y)) = f(x,y)$$

Hence, when $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,x)$ like before, we have $\lim_n t_n = 0$ and so $f(x,x) = g(0) = 1$.

Comment: This really follows from the continuity of $$g(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=0\\\frac{\sin x}x&x\neq0\end{cases}$$ Then $f(x,y)=g(x-y),$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$ is continuous. You can do it your way, but it will be much harder to read and understand, and prone to hidden errors.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree, writing $(x,y) \mapsto x - y \mapsto g(x-y)$ is what I usually do. But when I start moving limit signs around, it can get confusing, which was the reason I went this less readable way.

Comment: $\lim$ is usually taken to have higher precedence than $-$ so $\lim_n x_n - y_n$ should read $\lim(x_n - y_n)$. In any case, you need to prove the continuity of $g$ at $0$. You've hinted at that in your second proof but just stated it in your first proof.